# Node.JS allow access to run certain modules within Sandbox Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, sandbox, child-process

I am running Node.JS Sandbox module to create a Child Process and I need to be able to have my String Based Javascript access certain functions and Modules of Node. Right now, the Sandbox module is blocking all access to Node API's and functions outside of the Sandbox.

Example

```
function GetAccessTo() {
return "I want to call this function"
}

var str = "GetAccessTo();"
var s = new Sandbox();
s.run(str, function (output) {
output.result;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

To add methods to the `context` , go to Shovel.js and add methods to `var context`and you will be able to call from your Javascript String

Like this:

```
s.run("hi('something',function(result){return result})", function (output) {
                logic = output.result;
            });

    var context = Script.createContext();
        context.hi = function(a,b) {
            c="hi"
            return b(c)};
```